# Programmatically write to OneDrive folder in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, onedrive

Is is possible to programmatically write to the local machine's folder?  That is, I want to avoid sending through the REST API and write it directly to the disk and let OneDrive/SkyDrive do the uploading.

Prior to Win 8.1 it was possible to [detect the local OneDrive folder](https://superuser.com/a/728323/12163).  But this does not seem to be possible in Win 8.1.  Is there a way to still use the local folders with OneDrive?

Comment: Why don't you simple allow the user to save the file? They will be able to select OneDrive from the drop down, as well as any other app that implements the contract. More features, less work for you. And the OneDrive app does save to the local disk, the uploads happens asynchronously when a network is available.

Comment: That would be perfect if I could find where the user's OneDrive folder was!

Comment: That's the point: you don't have to, the user will. Or not. They have total freedom: local file system, OneDrive, DropBox, whatever. What is wrong with that? Why does it have to be OneDrive? Are you sure you don't want to write to the roaming app data folder instead? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.roamingfolder.aspx